# Laravel - How to Validate Grading System in Model and Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I am developing A web Application using Laravel-5.8 framework. I have a Model Class as shown below:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use App\Model;
class Gradesystem extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'grade_systems';
}
```

Also my Controller is shown below:

```
public function store(Request $request){
$request->validate([
  'grade_system_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
  'point' => 'required',
  'grade' => 'required',
  'from_mark' => 'required',
  'to_mark' => 'required',
]);
  $gpa = new Gradesystem;
  $gpa->grade_system_name = $request->grade_system_name;
  $gpa->point = $request->point;
  $gpa->grade = $request->grade;
  $gpa->from_mark = $request->from_mark;
  $gpa->to_mark = $request->to_mark;
  $gpa->save();
}
```

How do I validate, probably from the Model or the Controller between **from_mark and to_mark**. Also, from_mark should not be greater that or equal to **to_mark**. 
It must not allow a number that falls in the range of already existing value. For example if **from_mark** is **0 and to_mark** is 49 are already in database. So, if a user enters **from_mark or to_mark to be 30**, it must not allow it.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Laravel has documentation on validation. Read it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Answer (score 0):

For custom Validations its better use Rule Objects, where you can implement the logic of your validation.

An Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Uppercase implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return strtoupper($value) === $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be uppercase.';
    }
}
```

You can see the info in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-rule-objects)

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand entire validation you asked but this will help. With same way you can write any other validation on `from_mark` and `to_mark`.

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
 'grade_system_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
 'point' => 'required',
 'grade' => 'required',
 'from_mark' => 'required',
'to_mark' => 'required',
 ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
 return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors();
}

if ($request->get('from_mark') < $request->get('to_mark')) {
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors();  
}
```